# How do I read multiple integers from a file of an unfixed size into multiple variables in c++?

Tags: c++, file, variables, input, integer

I am trying to take integer data from a file, but I need the data in multiple varaibles. The files are in a format like this:

```
5 
1 3 10
2 4 15
3 6 8
4 7 3
5 9 12
```

The number in the first line goes into an int variable (*numPros*). For all lines after that, the three numbers go into three separate integer variables (*id*, *at*, and *ct* in that order).

This is the code I tried:

```
// Let user give input file
    cout << "Enter the input file name:  ";
    string in;
    cin >> in;
    cout << "\n\n";

    // Exit program if input file can't be opened
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open(in);
    if (!inFile)
    {
        cout << "Input file invalid or failed to open.\n\n";
        return 2;
    }

    // Get the number of processes from the input file
    numPros << inFile.get();

    // Create a list of jobs from the input file
    for (int i = 0; i < numPros; i++)
    {
        timer = 1000;

        int id, at, ct;
        id = inFile.get();
        at = inFile.get();
        ct = inFile.get();
        cout << id << " ";
        if (at < timer)
            timer = at;

        Job j(id, at, ct);
        jobList.push_back(j);
    }
```

*numPros*, *id*, *at*, and *ct* are int variables, as mentioned earlier. *Job* is a class I am using to store the variables together. *jobList* is a vector, used to hold the jobs. *timer* is irrelevant to my question, so you can ignore any lines involving it.

I was expecting this to work, but it just seems to create incorrect output. A test cout statement reveals that the *numPros* variable with the test file above was 0. Doing the came thing with the >> operator instead produced even more incorrect results, the numPros variable is set to 53, and that messes up reading the file (and even for the values it did read, the output was incorrect).

Comment: What does this statement numPros << inFile.get(); mean?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default-initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case that means changing `ifstream inFile; inFile.open(in);` to `ifstream inFile(in);`.

Comment: Usually, when you need multiple variables for a common purpose, you should look into containers, such as `std::vector`, and `std::list`.

Comment: Your problem is using `get` to read integers. No idea where you got that from, just `inFile >> numPros;` I think you need to consider where you are getting your information from. A good source is vital for learning C++

Comment: I don't understand.  Why are you not using `inFile >> numPros;` and `inFile >> id >> at >> ct; inFile.ignore(20000, '\n');`?

Comment: I'm guessing that you thought because you are reading from a file you had to do something different to read an integer. But the whole point of C++ I/O is that you **don't** have to do anything different, what works for `cin` and `cout` also works for a file.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews since `operator>>` will swallow line breaks, you don't need `inFile.ignore()` in this situation (and anyway, you shouldn't hard-code the size, use `numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()` instead).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `inFile.get()`, that reads in only a single `char`.  Use the `>>` operator to read in the integers, just as you do with the string filename, eg:

```
// Let user give input file
cout << "Enter the input file name:  ";
string in;
cin >> in;
cout << "\n\n";

// Exit program if input file can't be opened
ifstream inFile(in);
if (!inFile)
{
    cout << "Input file invalid or failed to open.\n\n";
    return 2;
}

// Get the number of processes from the input file
inFile >> numPros;

// Create a list of jobs from the input file
for (int i = 0; i < numPros; i++)
{
    timer = 1000;

    int id, at, ct;
    inFile >> id >> at >> ct;
    cout << id << " ";
    if (at < timer)
        timer = at;

    Job j(id, at, ct);
    jobList.push_back(j);
}
```